# I can see the full sea in view port but on camera view I can see only half of it or less

Tags: rendering, mesh, 3d-view

I am trying to do ocean 200m on the view port I can see it fully, but on camera view I can't see all of it, only half or even less.

What is the problem here? How can I make it full render on view port?

[image: Screenshot of Camera Perspective]

Comment: well....you question isn't totally clear. Maybe lemon's answer is what you want. Maybe you aren't aware, that your viewport (as you show it in your image) has other aspect ratio than your camera - which is the render resolution. So if you change that and move your camera, you can get the same as your viewport.

Comment: thank u for replying yes i ddint notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the viewport has, the camera has its own clipping distances:

[image]

Comment: thanks lemon , yes it worked i didnt reply cuz i dont wanna answer here its not for the rules i reckon but i appreciate it